# Python: How to display the position of a counter in a variable range as a text bar (similar to the progress bar)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, progress-bar

I'm trying to have a dynamic display for a continuously changing positive number in a range that is also changing. For concrete example, lets imagine its representing the dynamic price of a stock where the range is its current daily range.

Say the symbol is X, which opened at $100 today, went unto $125 intra-day and is now trading at $112.5. So ideally I'd like to display it as a dynamic progress bar:

```
X [####   ] 112.5 [100, 125]
```

If the stock then goes to 130 in the same day, the same progress bar should now look like

```
X [########] 130 [100, 130]
```

(Note: I'm placing no restriction on whether the *length* of the progress bar should change with increase in range - all i'm asking is that the current price should be accurately represented as a percentage of the range visually.)

Any ideas what packages I should look at (I really would prefer not having to implement it from scratch!!)

Please suggest a python 3.x approach if possible as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create it yourself using the print statement:

The basestring is `f"X [{variable}:>{length}] {value:.0f} [{value_min}, {value_max}]"`. What you have to find are the variables and set the length:

```
length = 20 # 20 characters
value = 112.5
value_min = 100
value_max = 125
percentage = ((value - value_min) / (value_max - value_min)) * 100
variable = '#' * int(percentage / 100 * length) # int is a floor function, you can deal with it how you like but we need an integer value.

string = f"X [{variable:<{length}}] {value:.0f} [{value_min}, {value_max}]"
print(string)
>>> X [##########          ] 112 [100, 125]
```

When you put this in a for loop you can also overwrite the previous line:

```
import time
for x in range(10):
    print(x, end='\r', flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

For example:

```
length = 20 # 20 characters
value = 112.5
value_min = 100
value_max = 125

for value in range(value_min, value_max):
    percentage = ((value - value_min) / (value_max - value_min)) * 100
    variable = '#' * int(percentage / 100 * length) 
    string = f"X [{variable:<{length}}] {value:.0f} [{value_min}, {value_max}]"
    print(string)
```

Output: (I did not overwrite the line to show the output).

```
X [                    ] 100 [100, 125]
X [                    ] 101 [100, 125]
X [#                   ] 102 [100, 125]
X [##                  ] 103 [100, 125]
X [###                 ] 104 [100, 125]
X [####                ] 105 [100, 125]
X [####                ] 106 [100, 125]
X [#####               ] 107 [100, 125]
X [######              ] 108 [100, 125]
X [#######             ] 109 [100, 125]
X [########            ] 110 [100, 125]
X [########            ] 111 [100, 125]
X [#########           ] 112 [100, 125]
X [##########          ] 113 [100, 125]
X [###########         ] 114 [100, 125]
X [############        ] 115 [100, 125]
X [############        ] 116 [100, 125]
X [#############       ] 117 [100, 125]
X [##############      ] 118 [100, 125]
X [###############     ] 119 [100, 125]
X [################    ] 120 [100, 125]
X [################    ] 121 [100, 125]
X [#################   ] 122 [100, 125]
X [##################  ] 123 [100, 125]
X [################### ] 124 [100, 125]
```

When the maximum value is changed:

```
length = 20 # 20 characters
value_min = 100
value_max = 125
values = [112.5, 125, 130, 110]

for value in values:
    if value > value_max:
        value_max = value
    percentage = ((value - value_min) / (value_max - value_min)) * 100
    variable = '#' * int(percentage / 100 * length) 
    string = f"X [{variable:<{length}}] {value:.0f} [{value_min}, {value_max}]"
    print(string)
```

Output:

```
X [##########          ] 112 [100, 125]
X [####################] 125 [100, 125]
X [####################] 130 [100, 130]
X [######              ] 110 [100, 130]
```

Comment: Does this still work when `value_min` and `value_max` can both change without changing the length of the bar displayed ? Using the same stock price example - the intra-day low and high can change as the day progresses

Comment: Yes as long as you update the way the percentage is calculated.

Comment: @TCSGrad I updated my answer.

Comment: One more thing - Ideally i'd like to not have my terminal fill up with each line, but the same line being continuously repalced with the current scenario. Should i just replace the `print` statement with `print(string, end = '\r')` ?

Comment: Yes that would indeed work, you can check it for yourself with the small example I placed in my answer. I added the `time.sleep` so you are able to see what happens ;).

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty simple example of how to make a status bar on the console:

```
import sys
import time

def progress(count, total, status=''):
    bar_len = 60 # the lenght of the status bar
    filled_len = int(round(bar_len * count / float(total)))

    percents = round(100.0 * count / float(total), 1)
    bar = '#' * filled_len + '-' * (bar_len - filled_len)

    sys.stdout.write('[%s] %s%s ...%s\r' % (bar, percents, '%', status))
    sys.stdout.flush()

a=0

while a < 50:

    progress(a, 100)
    a = a+5
    time.sleep(2)
```

So, in the example above, the progress function is recalled in that `while loop` until variable `a` reaches 50. So, the important thing is the `progress` function.

I hope I helped you!

Answer (score 1):

```
def progress_string(symbol, start, end, actual, bar_len=10):
    fill = int(bar_len*(actual-start)/(end-start))
    string = "#"*fill + " "*(bar_len-fill)
    if actual<start:
        string = " "*bar_len
    if actual>end:
        string = "#"*bar_len
    return "%s [%s] %.2f [%i, %i]"%(symbol, string, actual, start, end)


### TEST ###

START = 100
END = 125
X = 100
while X<=END:
    X+=.001
    time.sleep(.001)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print(progress_string("X", START, END, X, bar_len=25), end="\r")
```

This will also replace the progress bar each time.